# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error with webapp

Tags: ubuntu, dns

yesterday I installed a webapp on an ubuntu server virtual machine with virtualbox and I could access it with the page "https://kaapana:443" with google chrome.
Today I am with a different Wi-fi and the ip address of the virtual machine changed (I don't know if it matters) and when I tried to load the same page I got the DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error.

I already tried to add the line "supersede domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;" at the end of the "/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf" file and then executing the command "sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service", but it did not work. I also tried to manually add the line "virtual-machine-ip-address kaapana" in the "/etc/hosts" file and access the page with the ip address instead of the domain name kaapana, but neither attempt worked.

Do you have any idea what am I doing wrong? Thankyou very much for any help